# ¿Cómo podría hacer un botón de búsqueda en una página en la cual tengo los datos en una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla como esta mas o menos

```
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                CÓDIGO
            </td>
            <td>
                TÍTULO
            </td>
            <td>
                AUTOR/ES
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                C1-001
            </td>
            <td>
                Las TIC como herramientas de colaboración en etwinning
            </td>
            <td>
                Isabel Abril Pérez-Chuecos
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                C1-002
            </td>
            <td>
                Los MOOC en la formación continua del profesorado de ELE: Expectativas versus realidad
            </td>
            <td>
                Eva Álvarez Ramos y Leyre Alejaldre Biel
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

y me gustaría hacer un buscador por palabras mediante javascript pero la única manera que se me ocurre es dándole un Id a los "td" pero no me sirve ya que tendrían que buscar eso en concreto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado un ejemplo muy bueno:

Primero el HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Luego el CSS:

```
#myInput {
    background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Collapse borders */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase font-size */
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
    text-align: left; /* Left-align text */
    padding: 12px; /* Add padding */
}

#myTable tr {
    /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
    /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Por último el códgo Java Script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Borra toUpperCase() si no quieres que sea case sensitive

Cambia tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0] to [1] si quieres que la búsqueda sea por "Country" (posición 1) en vex de "Name" (posición 0).

Te dejo la URL (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) por si quieres obtener más información

Comment: Muchas gracias, he estado pensando y buscando ejemplos pero no encontraba nada, de nuevo muchas gracias.